# Render user login form with custom theme

Tags: 6, users

I have written a custom module, inside which I would like to create a custom user login block with custom theme applied. Now my question is "Inside my custom module, how do I get the user login form?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`drupal_get_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/6) to get the rendered form:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('user_login');
```

To override the default theme for the form have a look at [Theming the contact form in Drupal 6](http://11heavens.com/theming-the-contact-form-in-Drupal-6#Registerin) which goes through all the necessary steps very thoroughly.

Comment: I am able to retrieve the user login form, but how do I alter the form? For example, I would like to alter the value of $form["links"], how do I do that?

Comment: You would need to do that in [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), which would be called before the `$form` is returned to you in `drupal_get_form()`. The documentation should make it a bit more obvious what to do